# Check mime type of uploaded file in Django

Tags: django, file-upload

I have a website that allows users to upload images. To check the MIME type of the file the user uploaded I am using the following script that uses [python-magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic)

```
import magic
mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
if mime.from_file(request.FILES['media-pic']) not in ['image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']:
  # don't allow the file to be uploaded
```

However, when I try to upload a file, I get the error `coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, TemporaryUploadedFile found`. I didn't think it would work, but I tried `request.FILES['media-pic'].name` and got a `File does not exist` error.

How do I check the MIME type of the file before it has been saved on the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mime.from_file` expects a file name, and depending on the file size, the uploaded file might exist only in memory. You can instead use the `mime.from_buffer` method, using something like this:

```
f = request.FILES['media-pic']
# maybe even only read the first X bytes, might be enough for mimetype detection
mimetype = mime.from_buffer(f.read())
```